# dropdown slideUp again like it trigger twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below snippets, I did slide up (hide) the ul that has a class of "dpx" (the dropdown menu) when click anywhere on the document other than an element that has a class of "with_dpx" and its children/descendants however when I tried to hide (slideUp) it when click on any of the li element inside the ul that has a class of "dpx" (the dropdown), it did slideUp and and slideDown again like it triggered twice same also when I click the parent menu that has a class of "with_dpx", it did slide up and slide down again like it triggered twice, any ideas, help, suggestions, recommendations, clues is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".with_dpx").click(function(e){
        $(".dpx", this).slideDown();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
   $(".dpx li").click(function(){
       $(".dpx").hide(); 
    });
  
$(document).mouseup(function(e)
    {
        var container = $(".dpx");

        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {

                container.slideUp();

        }
    });
});
```

```css
.thehide{display: none;}
.dpx{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5px 0 0 #ffffff inset, 0 1px 2px 0 #B3B3B3;
}
.dpx li{list-style: none;}
.dpx li{
    padding: 5px 8px!important;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #555 !important;
    display: block !important;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="with_dpx">
    Menu 1
    <ul class="thehide extend clear display_table dpx" id="test">
         <li>hr approver</li>
         <li>manager approver</li>
         <li>attendance approver</li>
     </ul>
  </a>
  <a href=="#">
    Menu 2
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: add e.stopPropagation(); after e.preventDefault(); in $(".with_dpx").click handler

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have tried.

Instead of **slideDown**  use **slideToggle**

JS -

```
$(".with_dpx").click(function(e){
        $(".dpx", this).slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Use **not(".with_dpx")** so it will not consider event from the same element.

```
$(document).not(".with_dpx").mouseup(function(e)
    {
        var container = $(".dpx");

        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {

                container.slideUp();

        }
    });
```